# react-redux connect() function mapStateToProps is updating but component not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using React, Redux and React-Redux Provider function

```
const mapStateToProps = (store: any) => {
    console.log("mapStateToProps", store.textTwo);
    return store.textTwo;
};
```

if I use above `mapStateToProps` function to `connect` method of `react-redux` and update the state it will console.log changes in mapStateToProps function but not a rerendering component, not even it comes `componentWillReceiveProps` hook.

but when I add `spread operator` i.e. mutate the `mapStateToProps` return data it will re-render the complete component.

```
const mapStateToProps = (store: any) => {
    console.log("mapStateToProps", store.textTwo);
    return { ...store.textTwo }; <-- this will re render complete component
};
```

how to pass state to props of the component without re-rendering complete component.

--- Update ---

sample state data

```
store = {
    textTwo: {
        headerText: 'Sample',
        list: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'test 1'
            }
        ]
    },
    text: {}
}
```

`headerText` is a child component to show the header title.
the `list` is an Array of data that I'm iterating and listing name.

Tried below solution (given by @Siva Kondapi Venkata) and it's working but if I add a new item in the list, the header component is also re-rendering.

```
const mapStateToProps = (store: any) => ({
  textTwo: store.textTwo
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this. Return the `props` you are interested.

```
const mapStateToProps = (store: any) => ({
  textTwo: store.textTwo
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {

};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

Comment: thanks, it's working but its still re-rendering complete component, update the question added sample data and scenario, please review

Comment: @skdroid, If you are not using list in your child component, you can change it to `headerText: store.textTwo.headerText`.  If you are using the derived value from 2 properties, then you can use selectors (react-select). Can you also post the component code? to understand more better.

Comment: Actually I'm using both headerText and list, headerText  pass to the Header child component and the list pass to the list component, both components are basically functional component used to display data.